# Create A Method In Java

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

Hello I am trying to create a method in Java that Accepts an integer from the user. Calculate and display how many occurences of the integer are in the array(i'm Creating a random array) as well as what percentage of the array values is the entered integer.
This is how i create my Array:

```
public void fillVector ( ) 
    {

        int myarray[] = new int [10]; 

        for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) 
        { 
        myarray [i] = (int) (Math.random () * 10); 
        }
    }
```

Any sugestions how can i do to accomplish this ?

Comment: Ok, you have a method that fills an array with random numbers. What's the problem exactly, and what have you tried to do in terms of writing the ACTUAL method?

Comment: There should likely be several *different* methods, where each does a little bit of separate work. e.g. `fillRandomly`, `countOccurrences`, `buildHistogram` etc. All these "support" methods can/will be called by the "main" code that does something with the results - such as displaying the values to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a homework to you so I am not gonna give you the full solution but I will break down the steps of what you need to do in order to solve your problem. You have to find out how to code those steps yourself, or at least provide some code and your specific problem because your question is too vague right now.

1. Ask the user to input the number.
2. Store that number somewhere.
3. Check each cell of the array for that number. If you find one appearance
   increase the counter and continue until the end of your index.
4. Print out the appearances of the given number.
5. Print out the percentage of the cells containing the given value to the total amount of cells.

As I can see from your code (if it's yours) you are capable to pull this off on your own. It shouldn't be too hard.